# Errors using the Parcel-Bundler package

Tags: javascript, node.js, parceljs

I am running a Node.js/Express app using Parcel-Bundler.  I suspect that the error I am getting relates to Parcel-bundler. This is the error message:

bundle.js:17319 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Here is the code block where the error is:

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    });

**    console.log('Response: ', res);
    const userRole = res.data.user.role;**

    if (res && res.data && res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', 'Logged in successfully!');
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        switch (userRole) {
          case 'admin':
            location.assign('/me');
            break;
          case 'user':
            location.assign('/');
            break;
          default:
            location.assign('/');
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

The console.log clearly shows that res.data is not undefined. Yet the next line of code causes the error. Has anybody ever had such an issue?

Thanks
Leon

I looked at the GitHib repository for Parcel and notice that a few bugs have been reported. But I was not able to resolve my problem.